How do I report to Springer a scientific fraud to a cryptographic paper published in Springer?
I was reading a study listed in Springer. The study reviews the literature for solving the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem through index calculus.
But some of the previous works cited seems to not exist. For example:

Takagi [19] introduced index calculus as a method for solving the ECDLP on abelian varieties of small dimensions. Proposed approach solved a system of polynomial equations in many variables by generating a Gröbner basis of a curve associated polynomial ideal. The algorithm’s stages are as follows: First, choose a prime p with a low embedding degree k for the elliptic curve E over Fp. Determining E’s endomorphism ring, which is isomorphic to the maximum order of a quaternion algebra and the Gröbner basis for the ideal of polynomial interactions between E endomorphisms, comes next.
Finally, solve multivariable polynomial problems using linear algebra and the theory of Chinese remainder. The complexity of the method in Fp is sub-exponential in p’s bit length: O(exp(2(2 k/3)) * log(p)(3/2)). As a result, ECDLP security becomes finite field security.

With the quote being:


Takagi T (2009) Index calculus for abelian varieties of small dimension and the elliptic curve
discrete logarithm problem. J Cryptol 22(4):545–572


While a paper with this title exists, it wasn’t published by this author and claims to avoid working in the way described above/in this article.
There are several issues like: papers from real authors working in the field that the authors never wrote. Or even outright technically questionable affirmations like the original Coppersmith’s algorithm can be adapted in an inefficient way to work in elliptic curves. Not to mention peoples who write index calculus algorithms try to avoid using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.
That might had been okay, for a paper performing its own research for developing new algorithms, but the aim of the paper is to perform a review of the existing literature (which in large part don’t exist).
I know Springer is supposed to be a peer reviewed journal, but obviously things were overlooked. I wrote to the authors, but of course they didn't reply. So, how/where should I send my concerns about the trustworthiness of such paper?
Update
Although funny since I’m struggling for My Master degree

Dear Dr. Cellier,
Thank you for contacting Springer Nature. 
Please be informed that I have raised your concern to the Editorial Office for further assistance. They will get back to you as soon as they can.
If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to contact us quoting your Ticket ID [#9406332].
With kind regards,
--
Sophia Punzalan
Journal Support Specialist
Publishing Support
Springer Nature Group
www.springernature.com
--
Visit Springer Nature Support for answers to our most frequently asked questions.
-- 
Every day around the globe, our imprints, books, journals, platforms and technology solutions reach millions of people – opening the doors to discovery for our communities by enabling them to access, trust and make sense of the latest research, so that they can improve outcomes, make progress, and benefit the generations that follow.


This text looks very weird. Hallucinated citations are a sign that an AI wrote it, but on the other hand the obvious English mistakes are a sign that an AI didn't write it.

I realize this is a fairly technical question where discussion might lead to well-crafted answers -- please use this chat, and not the comments, for such discussion. Comments below this one should suggest improvements to the question or request clarification. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Springer is not a journal. Springer is a publisher, with several thousand journals in their portfolio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springer_Science%2BBusiness_Media

@FedericoPoloni: perhaps they just generated citations by AI and then have rewritten these.

@cag51 does it need to be technical though?

For conference proceedings, it is often fair to assume that they have not been peer reviewed, or the peer review was very superficial. So, without further information about the conference, I would treat them in the same manner as papers on a preprint server.

I assume that this is an article published in a reputable journal. In that case, it doesn't matter who the publisher is - they just provide some infrastructure and tech support and take the money. What matters is the editorial board of the journal itself.
A concern like the one described here should be raised to the editor-in-chief of the journal.
Contacting the publisher would make sense if the problem is with a book, not a journal article; or if an entire disreputable journal is published by a somewhat reputable publisher such as Springer.

I found the paper on-line.  It is (in my opinion) published in a very low quality conference proceedings which nevertheless were published by Springer.  The 68 papers in the book are from a very wide range of topics.  In my opinion the OP should give up and move on, but I agree that addressing the editors of the conference is the thing to do (unless they want to persuade Springer to drop this conference completely).

@HugheyDrambuie this is the practical approach but not being a good scientific citizen. The quality of the venue should not affect OP’s actions.

@AbhishekDivekar I accept this rebuke(!) and accordingly have written myself to a Springer editor that I used to work with.  The OP should write to the volume editors; I don't think it is appropriate for me to name them here but email addresses can be found with a little bit of work.

Disclaimer: I am no expert in cryptography, and cannot assess whether your concerns about the overall quality of the review you are mentioning are valid. However, I can use Google Scholar, and confirm that the only entry titled Index calculus for abelian varieties of small dimension and the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem was neither written by Takagi nor published in J Cryptol.
This being said, I would play the angelic cop and recommend not to see malice where there might simply be an honest error. If you spotted an error, it should be reported. To whom? The angelic cop that I am is going to agree with everyone at the same time, and would recommend to notify everyone (sending an email does not cost a lot of money, and the worst that could happen is you not receiving an answer): this includes the authors, editors, and series editors of the book you were reading. Contacting the mothership (Springer) does not hurt either. The legitimate authors of the wrongly quoted papers might also be interested.
Finally (this is a general comment about scientific fraud and dishonesty, and a simple erroneous quote might not justify this), if you are sure your concerns are serious, valid, and legitimate, you could further escalate them, e.g. by opening a discussion on PubPeer or contacting RW.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66712358#66712358

"a simple erroneous quote might not justify this" The OP is not complaining about a single isolated problem, but multiple ones: "There are several issues like: papers from real authors working in the field that the authors never wrote. Or even outright technically questionable affirmations ..."

@Neithea a completely mangled references section, whether through natural or artificial stupidity, could attribute articles to the wrong authors and journals. You could probably prove otherwise, or you could start by assuming it was done in error as a precaution

Yeah, uhm, this is very very obviously NOT a case of an innocent mistake. That approach is a valid one UNLESS there is significant evidence otherwise. As is the case here.

You can certainly report it to Springer, but if you feel like joining a particularly lovely community of scholars, you could also drop a comment at PubPeer: https://pubpeer.com/publications/606C31655898F92CB82587EEA8EA91
(I am assuming that the publication you refer to is 10.1007/978-981-99-4626-6_23)
The correct publication with that title is here: https://app.dimensions.ai/details/publication/pub.1047781667

If Springer published the article then you report it to Springer. They have a public face and a contact page linked from springer.com. The editor of the Journal of Cryptology is a known person and easy to find, so you report it to them. Give full details of your concerns.
Tsuyoshi Takagi also has a known email address. Perhaps he can enlighten you.
You suggest you have reported it without result to the authors, so that step is covered.
But note that it is conceivable that there is a simple explanation that might be hard to figure out. An unintentional error by the author, perhaps.

I was able to find where to report scam to Springer. How to submit papers to Springer but not where to report fraud in an Already published article.

I suggest editing this answer. The "Journal of Cryptology" (whose "employees" are experts in the field) is a very different entity from "Springer" (whose employees are people who do publishing work). You are, presumably, saying the OP should report this to the journal, not to Springer.

@AdamPřenosil, both, actually. Springer has responsibility for what they publish as does the specific journal. But, the reference itself might be the error.

@Buffy that s lot of citation that are hallucinated to be not fraud. Also 1987 Coppersmith for elliptic curve. Seriously? Check 10.1007/978-981-99-4626-6_23 doi.

@Buffy At this stage contacting Springer seems like a waste of time. It's not like they are going to form any opinion on this themselves. The important step is to convince the EiC that there is an issue, all other steps are secondary at this stage.

@AdamPřenosil, perhaps, but a senior editor at Springer can light the fire under some person with specific responsibility. Their reputation among scholars is their life-blood.

@Buffy In my experience, communicating with "Springer" these days largely means communicating with an at best semi-competent (but more often that one would imagine, a comically incompetent) employee of some random company where Springer outsources their publishing. It's possible that my negative experiences in this regard are an outlier – but it's also possible that your positive experiences no longer reflect the current reality of communicating with "Springer".

(I did not downvote the answer.)

Seconding @AdamPřenosil's comment about the tarnished knight
